Iphone safari mobile: Right click on link not working. When tap finger on link, link options not visible on my site
Iphone pro max 14, safari browser:
Mobile browser Right click on link not working.
When tap and hold finger on link, link options not visible on my site.
Generally, on mobile if you tap and hold finger on link it will show you option to open link on new tab, copy link, etc. But on my website, that is not happening.
For privacy reason, I can not add site link.
I want to see link options as I showed in attached image. I validated my site's html on https://validator.w3.org/ and fixed fatal errors.

